# jQuery copy all HTML code within an element to append to this element later on

Tags: jquery, html, search

Let's say I have the following HTML code with an input field to search:

```
<input class="form-control" id="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">

<div class="media">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="tag"><i>Some text</i></p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="tag"><i>Some text</i></p>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I use the code below to find all paragraph elements that contain my search query.

```
$html = $('.media>div');

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchstring = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $(".tag>i").each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

        $('.media').empty().append($html);

        if (text.indexOf(searchstring) > -1) {
            $(this).prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.col-md-12').prop("disabled", true).detach();
        }
    });
});
```

The search function works fine, exept that I can't seem to make a copy of all div's within the '.media' class which I need to append to '.media' everytime the keyup() event is fired. What do I need to assign to the $html variable in my example code for it to append later on?

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `clone()`:

```
$html = $('.media>div').clone();
```

or if you have any event attached with those inner divs you can pass a boolean value of `true` to have those events attached to the cloned ones too:

```
$html = $('.media>div').clone(true); // pass true to get the events attached
```

---

```js
var $html = $('.media > div').clone();

$('#clone').html($html);

alert($html.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='media'>
  <div>This is for clone.</div>
  <div>This is for clone.</div>
</div>
<hr>put cloned elements below this:
<hr>
<div id='clone'></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When i do alert($html.length) it returns 0.

Comment: @MarijnvanGool not able to replicate, just added a demo.

Comment: It probably isn't working because the HTML content is generated by the server and appended to the .media class by javascript.

Comment: @MarijnvanGool absolutely that might be the case, so you should put this clone method after you put those in the dom.

Comment: It seems to work now. But whether I use .clone() or not, it does seem to do the same thing. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Jai is right, use clone()

```
$allHtml= $('.media>div').clone();
```